# Open database backup file with .backup extension typically used with pgAdmin

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, database-backups

I received a database backup file from a governmental org with a .backup extension. It is about 1.4 GB. They said "This is a database backup file that we use within pgAdmin typically."

Would I need to install pgAdmin in order to view the contents? I have tried MS Excel and Notepad ++ but the file is too large. I do have MS Access, but I cannot seem to import it. Also I have SQL Server but I am not proficient in it.

Comment: The suggestion to use pgAdmin suggests it's a PostgreSQL dump, not a Microsoft SQL Server backup. Seems you'll need a quickstart on PosgreSQL. Added the postgresql tag to your question and removed sql-server.

Comment: By quickstart, do you mean I will have to learn about PostgreSQL? Or is quickstart like an express version of it?

Comment: I mean by quickstart to search the internet for a PostgreSQL tutorial. I think you'll need to develop a enough working knowledge to install it in order to restore and use it for your needs.